# Move CCCamera with the ccTouchesMoved method? (cocos2d,iphone)

Tags: iphone, camera, cocos2d-iphone, move

so I got this working:

```
-(void) ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

        for( UITouch *touch in touches ) {
            CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];   
            CGPoint prevLocation = [touch previousLocationInView: [touch view]];    

            touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: touchLocation];
            prevLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: prevLocation];

            CGPoint diff = ccpSub(touchLocation,prevLocation);
            [self setPosition: ccpAdd(self.position, diff)];
        }
}
```

I can move the layer with my finger BUT i want to move the cccamera but i don't have any experience with cccamera.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you very much
Have a nice day

:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I'm using... this implementation of moving the camera is something I found on the cocos2d forums.

```
-(void) ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    for( UITouch *touch in touches ) {
        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];   
        CGPoint prevLocation = [touch previousLocationInView: [touch view]];    

        touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: touchLocation];
        prevLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: prevLocation];

        CGPoint diff = ccpSub(touchLocation,prevLocation);
        [self setPosition: ccpAdd(self.position, diff)];

        // Get the camera's current values.
        float centerX, centerY, centerZ;
        float eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ;
        [self.camera centerX:&centerX centerY:&centerY centerZ:&centerZ];
        [self.camera eyeX:&eyeX eyeY:&eyeY eyeZ:&eyeZ];

        // Increment panning value based on current zoom factor.
        diff.x = 2 * diff.x * (1+(eyeZ/832));
        diff.y = 2 * diff.y * (1+(eyeZ/832));

        // Round values to avoid subpixeling.
        int newX = centerX-round(diff.x);
        int newY = centerY-round(diff.y);

        // Set values.
        [self.camera setCenterX:newX centerY:newY centerZ:0];
        [self.camera setEyeX:newX eyeY:newY eyeZ:eyeZ];
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I will accept it ;) but i have one problem: the touches aren't correctly detected when the camera is being moved.

Comment: and sorry for the late response :)

Comment: How are they not being correctly detected?  Are they not being detected at all, or just behaving strangely?

Comment: they were shifted but I corrected it by using [self convertTouchToNodeSpace];