# Camera following the touched body

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I need to have the Cocos2d camera follow a sprite (attached to a Box2D body) that the user is touching on the screen. As the user is dragging the player around, I need it to be able to go to other parts of the world. This has to be through touch, and not automatic scrolling.

I tried several approaches based on tutorials but nothing seem to address this issue. For example the solution offered here [Move CCCamera with the ccTouchesMoved method? (cocos2d,iphone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285020/move-cccamera-with-the-cctouchesmoved-method-cocos2d-iphone) by @Michael Fredrickson has the entire layer move, but when it moves, the sprites / bodies on the screen have unmatched coordinations and when I test to see if they're touched, the `if(fixture->TestPoint(locationWorld))` fails.

I also looked at the tutorials here http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/12/ways-scrolling-cocos2d-explained/ but this also isn't what I'm looking for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I'm accepting Liolik's answer below because it put me on the right track. The last piece of the puzzle, though, is to make the value received from the getPoint method an instance variable, and deduce it from `locationWorld` which I'm doing the `TestPoint` against. Like this:

```
UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];    
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
b2Vec2 locationWorld = b2Vec2(location.x/PTM_RATIO, location.y/PTM_RATIO);
b2Vec2 diff = b2Vec2(difference.x, difference.y);

for (b2Body* b = _world->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext()) {
    b2Fixture* f = b->GetFixtureList();
    while(f != NULL) {
        if(f->TestPoint(locationWorld-diff)) {
            b2MouseJointDef def;
            def.bodyA = _groundBody;
            def.bodyB = b;
            def.target = locationWorld-diff;
            def.maxForce = 9999999.0f * b->GetMass(); 
            _mouseJoint = (b2MouseJoint*)_world->CreateJoint(&def);
            b->SetAwake(true);
        }
     f = f->GetNext();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in update function :

```
CGPoint direction = [self getPoint:myBody->GetPosition()];
[self setPosition:direction];


- (CGPoint)getPoint:(b2Vec2)vec
{
    CGSize screen = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    float x = vec.x * PTM_RATIO;
    float y = vec.y * PTM_RATIO;

    x = MAX(x, screen.width/2);
    y = MAX(y, screen.height/2);

    float _x = area.width  -  (screen.width/2);
    float _y = area.height - (screen.height/2);

    x = MIN(x, _x);
    y = MIN(y, _y);

    CGPoint goodPoint = ccp(x,y);

    CGPoint centerOfScreen = ccp(screen.width/2, screen.height/2);
    CGPoint difference = ccpSub(centerOfScreen, goodPoint);

    return difference;
}
```

Comment: Liolik, what is "area" in your getPoint method?

Comment: OK I get it, the area is the size of my map (background image in my case.) So now I'm able to move around, while dragging my player, but after a while the touch looses contact with the player's body and the scrolling stops. I get it that I need to recalculate the place of the body to adjust with the new coordinates -- but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: I accepted the answer but please look at my "EDIT" in the question's body to see the last piece of the puzzle -- for what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

So if i understand correctly, when the sprite is inside of the middle of the screen, the background is stationary and the sprite follows your finger, but when you scroll toward the edge, the camera starts to pan?

I had something roughly similar in my game Star Digger where there's a ship in the middle of the screen on its own layer that has to fly around the world, and had the same problem when the ship fired bullets into the main world layer.

heres what I did:

```
float thresholdMinX = winSize*1/3;
float thresholdMaxX = winSize*2/3;

if(touch.x > thresholdMaxX) //scrolling right
{
  self.x += touch.x - thresholdMaxX;
}
else if(touchX < thresholdMinX)
{
  self.x += thresholdMinX - touchX;
}
else
{
  sprite.position = touch;
}
CGPoint spritePointInWorld = ccp(sprite.x - self.x, sprite.y - self.y);
```

then every time you calculate collisions, you need to recompute the sprites "actual" position in the world, which is its screen position minus the worlds offset, instead of the sprites screen position.

Comment: Thanks, @redux. So I guess you do the same calculations for each sprite in the world?